# Can you write a css-selector in BeautifulSoup that uses either the class or style to identify the desired info in a div?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I am scraping a webpage using BeautifulSoup, and there is a piece of information I want that is contained in a `<div>` and sometimes only has a value for `class` and sometimes only has a value for `style` like below:

```
<div class="text-one">
   Text I want
</div>


<div style="display-style">
   Text I want
</div>
```

Using Selenium, I would grab be able to grab the text I want, regardless of how it's formatted on the page, by doing this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(
        ".//div[contains(@class, 'text-one') or contains(@style, 'display-style')]"
        ).text
```

Right now I have a work around where I have an `if` statement to determine which selector to use to find the desired text (e.g. I do a string search of the raw HTML like:

```
if "<div style" in str(rawhtml):
   want = soup.find("div", {"style": "display-style"}).text
else:
   want = soup.find("div", {"class": "text-one"}).text
```

Is there an equivalent to the Selenium call I have above in BeautifulSoup? Or is determining the correct selector using an if-statement the only option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css OR syntax to specify to match either of those patterns.The "," is the OR operator. The [] indicates attribute selector and . class selector.

```
data = [i.text for i in soup.select("div.text-one, div[style='display-style']")]
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe there's no support for xpath in beautifulsoup, only for css selectors. If you are heavily invested in xpaths, the similar library lxml could be used instead:

```
from lxml import html
dom = html.fromstring('<html><div class="text-one">test i want1</div><div style="display-style">text i want2</div></html>','html.parser')
selection = dom.xpath(".//div[contains(@class, 'text-one') or contains(@style, 'display-style')]")
[n.text for n in selection]
```

Response: `['test i want1', 'text i want2']`